# Next.js Components: Error: error: Return statement is not allowed here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am running into an error when I add a new component into my Next.js Project where it gives the following:

`./components/GridMember.js
Error: error: Return statement is not allowed here

|
6 |     return (test);
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Caused by:
0: failed to process js file
1: error was recoverable, but proceeding would result in wrong codegen
2: Syntax Error`

[error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU5z5.png

I am unsure what is causing this as I should be able to return what I have. I have pasted the code below to the component

`import styles from './GridMember.module.css'

```
export default GridMember()
{
    return (<div>test</div>);
}`
```

and then the page has the following:

`import GridMember from "../components/GridMember";

```
export default function Work()
{
    return(
    <div>WORKING
        <GridMember/>
    </div>
    );
}`
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: `export default GridMember()` > `export default function GridMember()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing `function`
so you must write the code like this

```
import styles from './GridMember.module.css'


export default function GridMember()
{
    return (<div>test</div>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked.... silly of me to have missed that :D (It's monday...)

Answer (score 0):

in other case the below code also "Return statement is not allowed here". in such cases check the closing curly brace.

```
export default function Work()
{
//..........
}
    return(
    <div>WORKING
        <GridMember/>
    </div>
    );
```

```
export default function Work()
{
//..........

    return(
    <div>WORKING
        <GridMember/>
    </div>
    );
}
```